# Multiple paragraphs with different un-ordered lists

Tags: html

I have two unordered lists but the second one is trying to be a sublist to the first and is being indented. It looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to move the "Blog Post" out to the left like Seek Adventure is and then have the second unordered list be the sub-bullet to that "heading"

When I first tried troubleshooting I realized I didn't close my links and blog post became part of the link, but when I closed it still looks very odd.

This code is all in a function like this:

```
function badgerPass(){
    html = "";
    title ='<h3>Badger Pass - Yosemite</h3>';

    //seek adventure
    seekAdventureTitle = '<p>Seek Adventure</p>';
    seekAdventure = '<ul><li><a href="https://www.seekadventure.net/d/79-22-hours-of-driving-1-5-days-of-snowshoeing-yosemite-nationa">22 Hours of Driving, 1.5 Days of Snowshoeing, Yosemite National Park!</a></li></ul';


    //blogs
    blogTitle = '<p>Blog Posts</p>';
    blogs = '<ul><li><a href="https://socalhiker.net/snowshoeing-to-dewey-point-in-yosemite/">Snowshoeing to Dewey Point in Yosemite</a></li></ul';


    html = title + seekAdventureTitle + seekAdventure + blogTitle + blogs;
    return html;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You closed your UL incorrectly.

```
seekAdventure = '<ul><li><a href="https://www.seekadventure.net/d/79-22-hours-of-driving-1-5-days-of-snowshoeing-yosemite-nationa">22 Hours of Driving, 1.5 Days of Snowshoeing, Yosemite National Park!</a></li></ul';
```

Should be :

```
seekAdventure = '<ul><li><a href="https://www.seekadventure.net/d/79-22-hours-of-driving-1-5-days-of-snowshoeing-yosemite-nationa">22 Hours of Driving, 1.5 Days of Snowshoeing, Yosemite National Park!</a></li></ul>';
```